# MS-Access - Query to return each subset of records based on criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

How would I go about writing a query that results in the following...

Let's say my dataset looks this:

```
| PersonId | LastName | FirstName | ProductType | ProductValue |
|----------|----------|-----------|-------------|--------------|
| P0000001 |  Bloggs  |    Joe    |      1      |      £15     |
| P0000001 |  Bloggs  |    Joe    |      1      |      £20     |
| P0000001 |  Bloggs  |    Joe    |      2      |      £10     |
| P0000001 |  Bloggs  |    Joe    |      3      |      £5      |
| P0000002 |    Doe   |   Jane    |      2      |      £25     |
| P0000002 |    Doe   |   Jane    |      3      |      £60     |
| P0000003 |   Brown  |    Jim    |      1      |      £20     |
| P0000003 |   Brown  |    Jim    |      3      |      £5      |
```

Where a `PersonId` has at least 1 occurance of `ProductType = 1` in any of that `PersonId`'s set of records, return all records for that `PersonId` (even if the other records returned from the set have a `ProductType` that is not 1).

So the above dataset would be filtered like so:

```
| PersonId | LastName | FirstName | ProductType | ProductValue |
|----------|----------|-----------|-------------|--------------|
| P0000001 |  Bloggs  |    Joe    |      1      |      £15     |
| P0000001 |  Bloggs  |    Joe    |      1      |      £20     |
| P0000001 |  Bloggs  |    Joe    |      2      |      £10     |
| P0000001 |  Bloggs  |    Joe    |      3      |      £5      |
| P0000003 |   Brown  |    Jim    |      1      |      £20     |
| P0000003 |   Brown  |    Jim    |      3      |      £5      |
```

Jane Doe didn't have any records with `ProductType = 1` so all her records were filtered-out. Both Joe Bloggs and Jim Brown have at least 1 record with `ProductType = 1` so **all** their records are returned in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use GROUP BY and HAVING clause:

```
SELECT PersonID, LastName, Firstname
FROM tbl
WHERE ProductType=1
GROUP BY PersonID, LastName, FirstName
HAVING COUNT(*) >=1
```

And then you use IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE PersonID IN (
  SELECT PersonID
  FROM tbl
  WHERE ProductType=1
  GROUP BY PersonID
  HAVING COUNT(*) >=1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with an `EXISTS`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    yourTable as tbl
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            yourTable AS tbl1
        WHERE
            yourTable.PersonId=tbl.PersonId
            AND tbl1.ProductType=1
    )
```

This will get you the output:

```
P0000001    Bloggs  Joe 1   £15
P0000001    Bloggs  Joe 1   £20
P0000001    Bloggs  Joe 2   £10
P0000001    Bloggs  Joe 3   £5
P0000003    Brown   Jim 1   £20
P0000003    Brown   Jim 3   £5
```